# Recreate to_track_quat with two vectors using python

Tags: python, scripting, mathematics, quaternion

i've been asked to recreate the to_track_quat function of mathutils to create a quaternion that looks from point a to point b, but so far i've been un successful.

I'm using in blender two objects, being their positions:

object.location = mathutils.Vector((0,0,3))

target.location = mathutils.Vector((2,4,4))

angle = look_at(object, target)

Here is my first function:

```
def look_at(u, v):
    u.normalize()
    v.normalize()
    dot = u.dot(v)
    cross = u.cross(v)
    q = mathutils.Quaternion()
    q.x = cross.x
    q.y = cross.y
    q.z = cross.z
    q.w = math.sqrt(u.length_squared*v.length_squared) + dot
    q.normalize()
    print(q)
    return q
```

Returns (w=0.9129, x=-0.3651, y=0.1826, z=0.0000)

The result is something like this:

[image]

I believe i'm missing an operation, but i'm not certainly sure what.
Can someone guide me a bit on how to do it properly?

Another attempt that has been suggested:

```
def look_at(u, v):
    w = (v - u)/math.sqrt((v.x - u.x)**2 + (v.y - u.y)**2 + (v.z - u.z)**2)
    up = mathutils.Vector((0,-1,0))

    q = mathutils.Quaternion()
    cross1 = w.cross(up)
    dot1 = w.dot(up) 
    q.x = cross1.x
    q.y = cross1.y
    q.z = cross1.z
    q.w = math.sqrt(w.length_squared*up.length_squared) + dot1
    q.normalize()
    return q
```

Comment: In maths, a vector is not a point, even though we use the same data structure to store both. Normalising points (u and v) makes no sense.

Comment: I'm kind of aware since when i did put it in it made no difference, but i comment it in an out just in case to get some hope when i try new stuff.

Comment: You have to compute `w = (v - u)/|v - u|`, and then compute the angle between the forward vector of the object and `w` to compute the correct rotation.

Comment: With that do you mean to subtract the two vectors and divide it by the module of the subtraction of the vectors?

Comment: That's the mathematical notation of the normalised vector from `u` to `v`.

Comment: This got me closer to the result, it looks like it's almost there, but seems that i'm missing something. I'm trying different foward vectors to get the solution. it's giving me  almost the opposite rotations with this one. i'll update the post.

Comment: Just know that you also need a 2nd rotation around `w`, to ensure that the up-vector is pointing upwards again. Without this, you have an underspecified problem, with an infinite number of solutions, resulting in unwanted behaviour.

Comment: As a side note recommend using : `w = (v - u).normalized()`

Answer (score 3):

Based on this [tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera) I wrote this function

```
def look_at(camera_position, target_position):
    """Returns model-view matrix from camera position to target.

    # Arguments
        camera_position: Numpy-array of length 3. Camera position.
        target_position: Numpy-array of length 3. Target position.
    """
    camera_direction = camera_position - target_position
    camera_direction = camera_direction / np.linalg.norm(camera_direction)
    camera_right = np.cross(np.array([0.0, 0.0, 1.0]), camera_direction)
    camera_right = camera_right / np.linalg.norm(camera_right)
    camera_up = np.cross(camera_direction, camera_right)
    camera_up = camera_up / np.linalg.norm(camera_up)
    rotation_transform = np.zeros((4, 4))
    rotation_transform[0, :3] = camera_right
    rotation_transform[1, :3] = camera_up
    rotation_transform[2, :3] = camera_direction
    rotation_transform[-1, -1] = 1
    translation_transform = np.eye(4)
    translation_transform[:3, -1] = - camera_position
    look_at_transform = np.matmul(rotation_transform, translation_transform)
    return look_at_transform
```